# How can I fix response text?

Tags: android, response

I use Google Cloud Vision Api (Text_Detection) it is working normal but when I return answer from the Google, message style like image

I want just one text e.g "ACADEMIC PLANNER" so how can I remove front of Academic "null:" and other words?

Image e.g

[image]

And here is my code;

```
private String convertResponseToString(BatchAnnotateImagesResponse response) {
    String message = "I found these things:\n\n";

    List<EntityAnnotation> labels = response.getResponses().get(0).getTextAnnotations();
    if (labels != null) {
        for (EntityAnnotation label : labels) {
            message += String.format("%.3f: %s", label.getScore(), label.getDescription());
            message += "\n";
        }
    } else {
        message += "nothing";
    }

    return message;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:

```
private String convertResponseToString(BatchAnnotateImagesResponse response) {
    String message = "I found these things:\n\n";
    List<EntityAnnotation> labels = response.getResponses().get(0).getTextAnnotations();
    if (labels != null) {
      message += labels.get(0).getDescription();
    } else {
      message += "nothing";
    }
    return message;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your score is probably `null`. Do this:

```
message += String.format("%s", label.getDescription());
```

To have only one word, you make your method look like this:

```
private String convertResponseToString(BatchAnnotateImagesResponse response) {
    String message = "I found these things:\n\n";

    List<EntityAnnotation> label = response.getResponses().get(0).getTextAnnotations().get(0);
    if (label != null) {
            message += String.format("%s", label.getDescription());
            message += "\n";
    } else {
        message += "nothing";
    }

    return message;
}
```

Comment: Yeap. it is true thank you and other problem do you have any idea ?

Comment: Nope isnt work it dont accept "label.getScore(), label.getDescription());"   and why you write twice .get(0)
 ?

Comment: İf you want here is full code: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-vision/tree/master/android/CloudVision

Comment: Again problem.I think we use for because if dont use the for this code is not accepted "label.getDescription()"

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question correctly, then you just need to sanitize the label's *description* with [`substring()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int) and [trim()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim--) methods of the `String` class. Here is the modified version of your code:

```
private String convertResponseToString(BatchAnnotateImagesResponse response) {

    String message = "I found these things:\n\n";
    List<EntityAnnotation> labels = response.getResponses().get(0).getTextAnnotations();
    if (labels != null) {
        for (EntityAnnotation label : labels) {
             // 5=index of the character after "null:" (zero-based array counting), trim() removes whitespace on both sides of the string.
            message += String.format("%.3f: %s", label.getScore(), label.getDescription().substring(5).trim());
            message += "\n";
        }
    } else {
        message += "nothing";
    }

    return message;
}
```

**PS:** From the documentation, [`getDescription()`](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/vision/v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/vision/v1/model/EntityAnnotation.html#getDescription()) method returns a string and [`getScore()`](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/vision/v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/vision/v1/model/EntityAnnotation.html#getScore()) returns a Float. I bet the scores are not giving you any issues. I haven't tested on your actual data.

Comment: Nope it isnt work. I try but ı get eror. imgur.com/uEckW8Z  Android studio not allow this code, another idea ?

Comment: İf you want here is full code :https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-vision/tree/master/android/CloudVision

Comment: Oops, these methods are only available on strings and `EntityAnnotation` isn't a string... I tested my tweak on an array of strings, sorry; see the edited answer.

Comment: Yeah ı try and ı have few question. Code works only one line text image.But multi lines doesnt work.I get eror maybe this helpful for you,and thank you for your help,who vote downvote really ?  Eror:  E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
                  Process: com.google.sample.cloudvision, PID: 3710
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()     Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=2